# memory declaration in solidity returns

Tags: solidity

I have a simple question about solidity memory declaration:
It both return bytes data in following two cases, but one needs to have memory keyword and another does not.
I am a bit confused about the theory behind the scene. It will be appreciated anybody can help to clarify it.

```
function toBytes(string memory data) pure external returns(bytes memory) {
    return bytes(data);
}
function keccakBytes(string memory data) pure external returns(bytes32) {
    return keccak256(bytes(data));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that the first function returns `bytes`, and the second one returns `bytes32`, the difference being that the former can have an arbitrary length, while the latter is limited to 32 bytes.

The `bytes32` will fit in a single item on the stack, but `bytes` can have a length greater than 32 bytes. Since the number and length of items on the stack is limited, this means that `bytes` need to be written to memory. The stack is also cheaper to use (in terms of gas), so that's why `bytes32` uses the stack instead of memory.

You can read more about the stack, memory (and storage) in [the Solidity documentation here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html#storage-memory-and-the-stack).